# Error con conexion a BBDD Netcore SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo un problema de conexión a la bbdd al clonar un proyecto, me han saltado excepciones al conectar con el servidor de bbdd ya que a parte de que cambiar de nombre el servidor tambien tiene otra forma de autentificación, este es el error al querer correr el proyecto:

'An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.'

[image: Parámetros Server OK]

Y este es el servidor donde quiero correr la aplicación:

[image: nueva conexión Servidor]

Aqui el json donde se declara la conexión a la bbdd:

```
    {
         "Logging": {
         "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
    },
        "AllowedHosts": "*",
        "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Conexion": "**data source=DESKTOP-J2LFSFO; initial catalog=prueba; user id=sa; password=1234; 
         MultipleActiveResultSets=true**"   
    }
 }
```

A parte de cambiar el nombre del servidor, también se autentican diferente... como debería modificar el json?
Gracias !!

Comment: Como anillo al dedo

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar la forma de autenticación de Sql Server a autenticación de Windows debes eliminar de la cadena de conexion user id=sa; password=1234 y reemplazarlo por Integrated Security=True

```
Data Source=IBLAESBARC00213;Initial Catalog=prueba;Integrated Security=True
```